# First test automation framework attempt

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

Please help with my code. I started my very first test automation framework using Java, Maven, Selenium and Intellij and followed this guide - https://devqa.io/develop-test-automation-framework-scratch/ . If you go through the guide and at the end of part 2 it says a Chrome window should pop up when i run my code. I am having some issues and was hoping someone could go through it and tell me where I'm going wrong. Thanks in advance!

[Two of my dependencies are highlighted as weak warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZeDN.png)

Tried to run code after completing framework. Hoped a chrome window would pop up upon completion but running into some issues.
[Here is what messages I get when i run this class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moLLp.png)

Here's a GitHub link to my project - https://github.com/TravisB97/TravisTAF/commit/ce1b906bc43ea6faa0f23ac891bc8a82492be667